# Customize pe:documentViewer Button Behavior

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, primefaces-extensions

my problem is withe the component `pe:documentViewer` in PrimeFaces Extensions and precisely with the print element which you can see in the photo and what I want is to bind the print function with my code and not use the default one if there is a way to customize thank to say to me if there is no way there is any idea to not show the print icon 
thanks.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a way with some clever jquery to override the print button but it might be quite difficult.  However you can HIDE the print button if you want here is some code I wrote to do just that.

1. Load this JavaScript method somewhere in your page.

```
/**
 * Hides a button on the PDF Viewer toolbar
 */
pdfHideButton : function(button) {
    $('iframe').on('load',
            function() {
                var head = $(this).contents().find('head');
                var css = '<style type="text/css">#' + button   + '{display:none};</style>';
                $(head).append(css);
            });
}
```

2. Add this to your XHTML page which will execute this JavaScript this with the Document Ready function it will remove the button.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
           pdfHideButton('print');
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks Meoware , can you give me just a sign if you know how to override the print button using jquery and thank you again

Comment: Well if you look at the generated HTML of DocumentViewer you can "find" the Print Button.  Once you know what button is the Print button you can probably subscribe a Jquery OnClick event to it and turn off its current events.